# Sharing/transfer cart between customers in Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, sharing

Is it possible to transfer any quote of 1 customer to another customer in Magento?

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on it and found a solution, to share 1 customer's cart items to another customer's cart use below code, in observer or anywhere you want, as per your need:

`Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId)->setCustomerId($customerId)->save();`

This solution is working for me!

Comment: I think this will transfer the cart but if the product is removed from one customer it will be removed from another customer cart too.